# Bootstrap dropdown needs two clicks on mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap dropdowns on my top panel.
The problem is, that in mobile devices (touch devices), when I open one dropdown, to open another one I need firstly to click somewhere to close it and then just open the next dropdown.

For generally, I need two clicks to open other dropdowns. I need only one click (like on desktop).

https://peterlyshak.github.io/BidexAdmin

Thanks for help!